# I want validation expression for required field validator and the numeric validator together for phone number

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want validation expression for required field  validator  and the numeric validator together
for phone number

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhonenumber" runat="server" MaxLength="11" TabIndex="11" onKeyPress="return validateNumbersOnly();" ></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Phone Number" ControlToValidate="txtPhonenumber" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

this code works only if field is empty

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhonenumber" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers" Display="None" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

ValidationExpression="^\d+$"
use this for numeric format validation

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhonenumber" runat="server" MaxLength="11"  ></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Phone Number" ControlToValidate="txtPhonenumber" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhonenumber" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers" Display="None" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: give some explanation on your answer.